# How to display the table header with df.take()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, watson-studio

The default behaviour for `df.take()` on Watson Studio Jupyter notebooks does not display the header for the table whereas `df.show()` does:

[image]

I would like to use `df.take()` because the output is much easier on the eye :) - Is it possible to get `df.take()` to display the header?

---

NOTE:

- I don't want to use `show()`.
- I want to use `take()` and I want `take()` to display the header.

Comment: take will return you the Array[Row] but show is the api to give you the tabular view of the dataframe. What exactly your expected output. if you want to get limited records then you can use limit api with show

Comment: In scala, `take` expects a number and outputs a number of rows. So, no, you can't use `take`. Why not just use Pandas `take` and call it a day? You will get the header.

Comment: @A.J.Alger thanks!  The problem is that this is scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to let `take` show the headers. Header information is in the dataframe, but `take` returns a plain list or array, not a dataframe.

- Python: [DataFrame.take](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.take)
- Scala: [Dataset.take](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@take(n:Int):Array[T])

As suggested in another answer, `limit` would return a dataframe with header information, on which you could call `show`.

- Python: [Dataframe.limit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.limit)
- Scala: [Dataset.limit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@limit(n:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T])

But since you insist on using `take` and on not using `show`, the answer is No. `take` is not meant to do what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Limit can be used:

```
df.limit(5).show()
```

Comment: I want to display the header with `take()` - I don't want to output the table with `show()`